# Ember Qunit helpers not working

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-testing

I have been checking ember qunit testing using ember helpers like in official [documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/testing-controllers/) . checking the examples (that are not working) I can see that they use a js library

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit-builds/master/dist/globals/main.js"></script>
```

But I cannot find this url. I guess that this library contains the expect and visit function definition. So I cannot get qunit test works. There is any place to download ember helpers js library?, are official web site examples wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ember-qunit library that you are looking for can be downloaded from GitHub:

https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit-builds

You can either access the library remotely:

```
<script src="https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit-builds/blob/master/ember-qunit.js"></script>
```

Or you can download it locally, place it alongside your other scripts and include it by specifying the relative path to the library, replacing the remote path you are currently specifying.